# Flutter How to identify flutter android application is installed and using in BlueStacks windows application - PC?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know whether flutter android application is installed and using in BlueStacks windows PC. Actually i need to prevent installing flutter application in Bluestacks. Is it possible to prevent or identify whether application is using from Bluestacks or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can turn off the usb debugging in bluestacks. And it wont install it from the Android studio or any editor

Comment: Hi @KrishBhanushali thanks for the reply but actually i need like blocking installation of my playstore released app coz i dont want my user to use my app from BlueStacks or how can i know these users are using my app through BlueStakcs? i need my users to install and use in Real Device only!